# pure vba SiteData.GetListCollection use in Excel 2010

Tags: sharepoint, excel, vba

I need just the final step. Maybe it's stupid but .. what am i missing here?. I'm trying to get all the lists of a SharePoint site. If I debug I can see the correct tree in the locals pane, but the SelectNodes("//_sList") returns no childs ...

```
Sub MyTest()
Const urlRef As String = "http://MySite/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx"
Dim WebRequest As New XMLHTTP60, strRequest As String
WebRequest.Open "POST", urlRef, False
WebRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
WebRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListCollection"
strRequest = _
    "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> " & _
    "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'> " & _
    "  <soap12:Body> " & _
    "    <GetListCollection xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/' /> " & _
    "  </soap12:Body> " & _
    "</soap12:Envelope>"

WebRequest.send strRequest

Dim docResponse As New DOMDocument60
Set docResponse = WebRequest.responseXML

docResponse.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
Debug.Print docResponse.SelectNodes("//_sList").Length ' >>> Returns 0!!!!
End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding the default namespace: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313372

Comment: I knew it!!!. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the corrected code...

```
Sub MyTest()
Const urlRef As String = "http://MySite/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx"
Dim WebRequest As New XMLHTTP60, strRequest As String
WebRequest.Open "POST", urlRef, False
WebRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
WebRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListCollection"
strRequest = _
    "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> " & _
    "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'> " & _
    "  <soap12:Body> " & _
    "    <GetListCollection xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/' /> " & _
    "  </soap12:Body> " & _
    "</soap12:Envelope>"

WebRequest.send strRequest

Dim docResponse As New DOMDocument60
Set docResponse = WebRequest.responseXML
docResponse.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'"

Debug.Print docResponse.SelectNodes("//x:_sList").Length ' >>> Now it Works!!
End Sub
```